# What does tightness actually mean?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, definition

I was recently introduced the following definition for tightness.

A sequence of random variables is called tight if for any $\epsilon >0$ there is $R>0$ such that for any $i$,
$$P(X_i\in[-R;R])>1-\epsilon.$$

I am having troubles understanding what it actually means graphically and I have tried to word it differently as well.

How I have understood it is that the probability that the sequence takes value on the interval $[-R;R]$ ...

and I don't understand the $1-\epsilon$ part. Why does the probability have to be larger than $1-\epsilon$? Is it the same if we just say it is smaller than $\epsilon$? Is there any way to word the definition in a way where there is no notations so I can understand it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know about quantifiers? The key in this definition is their order. We have
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0( \exists R > 0 ( \forall i \ P(X_i \in [-R, R]) > 1 - \epsilon))
$$
In other words, we can always pick an interval big enough that *all* of the $X_i$ are as likely to lie within it as we like.

It is in this sense that the $X_i$ are "tight." Intuitively, you can think of it as saying that the $X_i$ don't spread out too fast with $i$.

### Addendum

How could a sequence of random variables fail to be tight? Take $X_n$ with $P(a \leq X_n \leq b) = \int_a^b C_n e^{-\frac{x^2}{2n^2}} dx$ where the $C_n$ are constants chosen so that $P(X_n \in \mathbb{R}) = 1$. Then, for any $R \in \mathbb{R}$ there always exists $k$ (just take $k > R$) such that $P(X_k \in [-R , R]) < .7$. This shows that the $X_n$ are not tight. Roughly, this happened because $\sigma_{X_n} = n$. The $X_n$ are spreading out with $n$.